# Loading AngularJS template on a PhoneGap/Cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-directive, phonegap-build

My AngularJS app is running smoothly on the browser.
When putting it in a cordova app and running on a device,

*src/directives/js/nothing.js*

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .directive('nothing', function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: '../src/directives/html/nothing.html',
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: true
        };
    });
```

My template HTML is at:

*src/directives/html/nothing.html*

The error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND 
file:///android_asset/src/directives/html/nothing.html

Error: error:tpload 
Error Loading Template
```

As said, on the browser it works.

Comment: have you tried it like this: `templateUrl: 'src/directives/html/nothing.html',` ?

Answer (score 2):

also its very important to note that the  CaSE in the url must match exactly on IOS or you will also a super hard to track error.

Comment: Case can be an issue on Android also. (I've learnt this the hard way)

Comment: you and me both.. I have also had issue with the file renaming going through bitbucket to not be accurate so that the code is correct but the file name is still incorrect due to a weird get checkin. So  check that